# How can I use a php variable in a JSON request body?

Tags: php, json

I have a request body that looks like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":\"testuser5@so.com\",\"send_welcome\":true,\"welcome_message\":\"Test\",\"account_attributes\":{\"email_address\":\"testuser5@so.com\",\"first_name\":\"Snow\",\"last_name\":\"White\",\"middle_initial\":\"A\",\"phone_number\":\"2055551234\",\"address\":\"1 Main St\",\"city\":\"Detroit\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"zip\":\"48220\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"portals\":[],\"groups\":[],\"identification_card_numbers\":[]}");
```

I want to assign the username php variable to the "username" json parameter, but I keep causing 400 bad requests when I try:

```
$username = json_encode('something@something.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":" . $username . ",\"send_welcome\":true,\"welcome_message\":\"Test\",\"account_attributes\":{\"email_address\":\"testuser5@so.com\",\"first_name\":\"Snow\",\"last_name\":\"White\",\"middle_initial\":\"A\",\"phone_number\":\"2055551234\",\"address\":\"1 Main St\",\"city\":\"Detroit\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"zip\":\"48220\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"portals\":[],\"groups\":[],\"identification_card_numbers\":[]}");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
 $username = 'test@gmail.com';

 $json = json_encode(
    array(
        "username" => $username,
        "send_welcome" => true,
        "welcome_message" => "Test",
        "account_attributes" => array(
            "email_address" => "testuser5@so.com",
            "first_name" => "Snow",
            "last_name" => "White",
            "middle_initial" => "A",
            "phone_number" => "2055551234",
            "address" => "1 Main St",
            "city" => "Detroit",
            "state" => "MI",
            "zip" => "48220",
            "country" => "US"
        ),
        "Gender" => "Male",
        "portals" => [],
        "groups" => [],
        "identification_card_numbers" => []
    )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

Work with array and use json_encode() to get the JSON

**Why ?**

PHP dont work naturally with JSON like Javascript, and concatenate and construct a JSON with a raw string is a bad practice and a headache.

Comment: please use this method if you're working with other developers :D

Comment: oh i missed this in my answer. best one so far.+1

Comment: Honestly this is the better of the two answers as I agree with kip's assertion about working directly with JSON in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

When you encode the username it looks like this:

```
"something@something.com"
```

So, when you concatenate you're adding in the extra quotes, causing your JSON to be malformed. The result is:

```
{"username":""something@something.com""...
```

What you should do is just concatenate directly:

```
$username = 'something@something.com'; // do not encode
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"send_welcome\":true,\"welcome_message\":\"Test\",\"account_attributes\":{\"email_address\":\"testuser5@so.com\",\"first_name\":\"Snow\",\"last_name\":\"White\",\"middle_initial\":\"A\",\"phone_number\":\"2055551234\",\"address\":\"1 Main St\",\"city\":\"Detroit\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"zip\":\"48220\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"portals\":[],\"groups\":[],\"identification_card_numbers\":[]}");
```

Concatenating directly requires that you modify the JSON in `curl_stopt()` to add in the necessary backslashes for the value as well as the addition quotes to insure the concatenation happens correctly. That will insure your JSON is correct.

Comment: I deleted my comments (they don't make any sense now), and changed them to an upvote. I hope this is the correct behaviour on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the backup on this @jh1711 - yes, it would be what Stack considers good citizenry.

Comment: +1, this answer *explains* what's wrong with OP's code, instead of suggesting an outright different (albeit better) solution.

Comment: I appreciate your answer for explaining my mistake, just to let you know. I upvoted it as well. I only chose the other answer because it's a better practice than what I was trying to do and if somebody googles this, I'd rather they see the best practice first.